# How to restrict repo collaborators from approving pull requests?

Tags: github, pull-request

I'm managing a GitHub repo for a college team project, and so, I added my team members as collaborators on the repo

Since i'm the "owner" of the project, I want them to create their pull requests but have them be approved and merged only by me, but I can't seem to find any options relating to this

I already got the merge protection to ensure that no one can merge directly onto master without doing a PR from another branch

These are my :[current master branch settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBmcW.png)

Comment: CODEOWNERS might help here https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners -- then check the box that requires approval from code owners. You could alternatively lock the main branch so no one can merge into it but you. Also suggest check REQUIRE APPROVAL and set it to at least 1